# Application of trace theorem of Sobolev space in hypobolic equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, trace

Using the trace theorem $H^1(B(\overrightarrow{0},1))\hookrightarrow L^2(\partial B(\overrightarrow{0},1))$ and a change of variables, show that there exists $C_0>0$ such that for any $r>0$ and any $f\in H^1(B(\overrightarrow{0},1))$ the following holds:
$$\int_{\partial B(\overrightarrow{0},1)}|f|^2\leq\displaystyle \frac{C_0}{r} \int_{B(\overrightarrow{0},1)}|f|^2dx+C_0r\int_{B(\overrightarrow{0},1)}|\nabla f|^2dx$$

I would like to use the divergence theorem to change the left side of the inequality, but I really do not how to start.

Oh, sorry, I make a mistake in the above inequality, that should be 
$$\int_{\partial B(\overrightarrow{0},r)}|f|^2\leq\displaystyle \frac{C_0}{r} \int_{B(\overrightarrow{0},r)}|f|^2dx+C_0r\int_{B(\overrightarrow{0},r)}|\nabla f|^2dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The original statement is false.

   Consider the constant function $f\equiv1$.
   It is in $H^1$ and $\nabla f\equiv0$.
   Then your estimate becomes
   $$
   |\partial B(0,1)|
   \leq
   C_0r^{-1}|B(0,1)|
   $$
   for all $r>0$.
   If this is true, then it is also true in the limit $r\to\infty$.
   Taking this limit says that the surface measure of the ball is zero.
2. The corrected statement is true.

   Consider a function $f\in H^1(B(0,r))$ and define $g\in H^1(B(0,1))$ by $g(x)=f(rx)$.
   Then change the variables to turn integrals over $B(0,r)$ and its boundary into those for the unit ball.
   By continuity of the trace map for the unit ball we have the required estimate for $g$ when $r=1$.
   The three integrals get different scaling factors when you change variables, and this produces the coefficients $r^{\pm1}$.

Comment: Oh ,sorry, I make a mistake in the integral inequality, it should be $$\int_{\partial B(\overrightarrow{0},r)}|f|^2\leq\displaystyle \frac{C_0}{r} \int_{B(\overrightarrow{0},r)}|f|^2dx+C_0r\int_{B(\overrightarrow{0},r)}|\nabla f|^2dx$$

Comment: @RoonAnnHo I gave the steps to prove that. See the edited answer.